# How to protect an ADC input from a 100V AC voltage

Tags: adc, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

I would like to know to how to protect my ADC from a 100V AC 50Hz input to the analog inputs of the [ADS112C04](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads112c04.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1684524837285).

This ADC is used to measure a max differential voltage across a shunt of 50mVrms at 50Hz.

The ADC has the following builtin protection:
[image]

Where AVDD is +3.3V and AVSS is -3.3V.

The ADC has the following absolute specs:
[image]

Questions:

1. How do I limit the current to a max of 10mA, so as to not damage the ADC?
2. How do I protect the ADC inputs from overvoltage without causing a substantial error (1mV error, for 50mV the input into the ADC must therefore be 49mV or 51mV) in the ADC readings?

**EDIT 1:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuAZZn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "substantial error", i.e. what your system requirements are so it's hard to know what's acceptable.

Comment: @JohnD I want the error to be less than 1mV. Will add to the post

Comment: There are schemes like this: https://www.eeweb.com/high-voltage-protector-for-meters-by-ca3130/ and if you Google "multimeter input protection" you can find other options.

Comment: Can AVSS be -3.3V when the datasheet claims the absolute max to DGND is -2.8V?  Seems for bipolar supply, they reccomend +/-2.75V max.

Comment: @rdtsc correct. Sorry oversight, was thinking of another ADC, was suppose to be +\- 2.5V.

Comment: Can you please provide the intended shunt circuit and its supply? Then appropriate protection equipment might be found.

Comment: @Jens please see EDIT 1

Comment: In your area, is one leg of a mains power "neutral" (i.e. bonded to ground)? Or are both legs "live"?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy the neutral is tied to earth (ground)

Comment: Yes, neutral is bonded to ground. Is one of the wires in your schematic neutral? If so, do you know which one? In the US, we have polarized plugs. Do you have polarized plugs in your area?

Comment: The whole ADC side circuit needs an insulated supply and optocouplers or other isolators for the data lines. It is just too dangerous to rely on the AC line ground assignment.